# How to hide products of one admin user from other admin user?

Tags: magento

I have created user role merchant as well as create a user named crewsaga_seller. Now he can see product added by admin too. How should I restrict him that he can see product added by him only?

I tried the following changes in grid.php but I am getting an empty table.

```
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser(); 
if($admin->getUsername() !='your actual admin'){
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_user', $admin->getUsername());
}
```

Magento 1.9.2.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create an attribute for example all_magento_users (with input type dropdown) and define all the users in it (in your case crewsaga_seller, your_admin_user). Then assign this attribute to your attribute set.

2) Copy app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php to app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php so you can make changes in this file.

3) In function _prepareCollection() after this:

```
$store = $this->_getStore();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

add the following code:

```
$attr_code = 'all_magento_users'; //the name of the attribute you created
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_code);

if ($attr->usesSource() && ($admin->getUsername() != 'your_admin_user')) {  //your admin user, so you can see all products
    $product_value_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($admin->getUsername());
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attr_code, $product_value_id);
}
```

4) Create a product and append it to your user. The other users should not see it anymore.